# How do you set slimerjs as the engine for casperjs when using spookyjs?

Tags: node.js, casperjs, slimerjs, spookyjs

I'm driving casperjs through spookyjs and I want to use slimerjs, rather than phantomjs, as the engine for casperjs.

When using casperjs you set the engine when calling casperjs from the command line like this:

```
casperjs *scriptname* --engine=slimerjs
```

I thought it may be possible to set the engine when configuring casperjs when using spookyjs like this:

```
var spooky = new Spooky(
{
  child: {
          transport: 'http'
  },
  casper: {
          logLevel: 'debug',
          verbose: true,
          options: {
            clientScripts: ['public/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'],
            engine: 'slimerjs'
          }
  }
},...
```

But that doesn't work. So how do you use slimerjs as the engine when driving casperjs through spookyjs?

Comment: Opened [this issue](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/97) on the SpookyJS GitHub page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this workaround helps.
  As casperjs is a a python script that sets variables and starts slimmer/phantom, you can just modify the script to make slimmer it's default.
Just edit /usr/local/bin/casperjs, and set the engine (around line 86):

Instead of `ENGINE = 'phantomjs'` 
write `ENGINE = 'slimerjs'`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
var spooky = new Spooky(
{
  child: {
      transport: 'http',
      engine: 'slimerjs'
  },
  casper: {
      logLevel: 'debug',
      verbose: true,
      options: {
        clientScripts: ['public/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'],
        engine: 'slimerjs'
      }
  }
},...
```